# How can Apophis have a son?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Apophis refers to Skaara and his symbiote Klorel as his "son".

I can think of two explanations:

1. Apophis is a queen.
2. Goa'uld are capable of sexual reproduction.

It would make a lot more sense for Goa'uld to have the option of reproducing sexually as they have genetic memories.

A queen can only pass on her memories to her offspring whereas in theory, sexual reproduction would combine the memories, and DNA of the offspring allowing for mixing memories (like a Harcissus except in the form a symbiote instead of a human).

Comment: Good question! And welcome to the site. Please may you take the [tour] and check out the [help]. Share and enjoy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Male goa'uld reproduce with female goa'uld "queens" to produce offspring. Whether that's via a host body in the (ahem) usual human fashion, or by providing a sample of DNA to a [queen outside a human host](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/stargate/images/e/e6/Cure_%28Stargate_SG-1%29.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20071221225058) isn't immediately clear.

> **KLOREL:** Ah, Teal'c, the traitor. I will take great pleasure in delivering his head to my father.
>
> **O'NEILL:** He's not your father.
>
> **KLOREL:** **He is my father. He seeded the queen mother.** He chose the host in which I will live out eternity. Apophis gave me life.
>
> <sub><sup>[SG1: Within The Serpent's Grasp, Part I](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/1.22_%22Within_The_Serpent%27s_Grasp_Part_1%22_Transcript)</sup></sub>